# Use Typescript enum values to create new type

Tags: typescript

I have the following scenario:

```js
enum FieldsMap {
  User = "user-name",
  Password = "user-password",
  Country = "user-country"
}

type Fields = "user-name" | "user-password" | "user-country";
```

as you can see `Fields` is repeating the values of `FieldsMap`, is there a way that `Fields` can use the **values** of `FieldsMap` in order to avoid repetition?. Also, I'm using `FieldsMap` as an `enum` here, but I can change that if necessary, I'm just trying to avoid using strings as much as possible:

```js
const onChangeHandler = (key: Fields, value: string) => {
  switch (key) {
    case FieldsMap.User:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
    case FieldsMap.Password:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
    case FieldsMap.Country:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use the enum [normally](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglsANgEwM5QN4FgBQUoCqqwATlALxQBEYxJAtCAIYTBUA0u+ACk6qgHcA9iWQVqtUvQAOfQSOQcuUAMJCwIAC4kAnuJp16AY3VbdVXAF9cuEyFSaoQkCoAWTEAHNgACQ-JEUnEACgBrYB0ALlgEFFR2KAA3JkQwYGiHEjgvAEoKAD5MZUE4TSNXKDCIvOw8fCgjPmAYpDQAOiJSSOV6qAB6PqhkIShUIVZNV2zPKAFSioADZNTgBZ76gCMSYCZQgG51xuIWuLbefmFRbrregaGRsYmpr1n5qCWUtLWbze3dg5+R2a8FaqDaag02ii63wd2Go3GwEm01ek3eyy+MKgWx2+2U1hwlj2QA)?  I can't tell if you are missing the standard use case or if you have some other requirement that prohibits it...

Comment: There's no reason, I tried just that and it worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Update for TS4.1+: as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258486/2887218) points out, you can now use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to get the string representation of the values of the `FieldsMap` enums:

```
type Fields = `${FieldsMap}`;
// type Fields = "user-name" | "user-password" | "user-country"
```

But it's important to be sure you actually need this; the ordinary use case for `enum`s is that you don't want much of a dependency on the actual string literal values themselves; for an enum named `Foo`, the type `Foo` is already a union of the enum values, but they are treated nominally so you can't accidentally use the string in place of it.  If you really want to use the string in place of the value, it's possible you don't want an `enum` in the first place and should just use objects with string literals in them.  The point is: make sure this is what you really want before using it.

---

Just writing this out as an answer... in TypeScript, [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) essentially already have the behavior you're looking for without needing to define any additional types.

That is, the following enum definition:

```
enum Fields {
  User = "user-name",
  Password = "user-password",
  Country = "user-country"
}
```

brings into scope a *value* named `Fields`, with *properties* whose keys are `User`, `Password`, and `Country`, and whose values are `"user-name"`, `"user-password"`, and `"user-country"`, respectively, as you know.  This value makes it to runtime, as in:

```
const x = Fields.User; // makes it to the emitted JS
```

and is similar to the value:

```
const FieldsLike = {
  User: "user-name",
  Password: "user-password",
  Country: "user-country"
} as const;

const xLike = FieldsLike.User; // makes it to the emitted JS;
```

But it also brings into scope a *type* named `Fields`, which is equivalent to the *union* of the property values in the `Fields` object.  This type is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) with the rest of the type system when JS is emitted, but can be accessed at design time via type annotations and using IntelliSense, as in:

```
const y: Fields = x; // the "Fields" annotation is the type
```

and is similar to the type

```
type FieldsLike = (typeof FieldsLike)[keyof typeof FieldsLike];
// type FieldsLike = "user-name" | "user-password" | "user-country"

const yLike: FieldsLike = xLike; // the "FieldsLike" annotation is the type
```

This is the type you're looking for; see below.

By the way, the enum *also* acts as a namespace with exported types for each enum member:

```
const z: Fields.Password = Fields.Password; // type and value
```

(so the `Fields.Password` on the left is the name of a *type*, while the `Fields.Password` on the right is the name of a *value*).  Thus the types accessible under `Fields` are similar to the namespace:

```
namespace FieldsLike {
  export type User = typeof FieldsLike.User;
  export type Password = typeof FieldsLike.Password;
  export type Country = typeof FieldsLike.Country;
}

const zLike: FieldsLike.Password = FieldsLike.Password; // type and value
```

---

Whew, that means just using the `enum Fields { ... }` definition give us the behavior of  `const FieldsLike = ...`, `type FieldsLike = ...`, and `namespace FieldsLike` all at once.

Let's back up... the type you were looking for, the union of all properties under the `Fields` enum, is already a type named `Fields`.  (Okay, I changed the name of your `FieldsMap` to `Fields`), and you can use it directly:

```
const onChangeHandler = (key: Fields, value: string) => {
  switch (key) {
    case Fields.User:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
    case Fields.Password:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
    case Fields.Country:
      // do something with `value`
      break;
  }
};
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVAygFgIxIN4FgAoJJCYAVzCQDEBLCAGwBMoBZEGPIkkgVSggAnJAF4kAInIDBAWlCRxAGm48ACiChQA7gHtBTURKlCZcTbv1KVJAMI7ywAC6CAnocnSZ8e09fiVAL5EKo4uMMh0jCyGAAYAJLiRzGwcATEA3CoA9FlIoeE09MnuxrLyEOJIAD5GnmbaekyVNR4m3g7OLv6EwYRBPYRklIVRUFzESPxCJZ7lVhPq5o0zJvUWTcoTdh2uK7Ltvl1E-b3ewFCOSAAehkksAHRTgulIOUhgIADW0Ei0l446PIAC2QEDAf0cEAMACk0JkBmcLiNkgAZWjfQwECZPABctRMc02JEWDX0eNasjWjXmth8nXJpS8dL8xyQGiQiMc8KInOuaIxYjuUH5EEe0hebw+3zGfzygMcINI4MckJhcN6OU1Wu12tOOnOlxceKFhiuEtyCuQ4iFlRAwGAOkcIEctH1vzGlryYQgvXyESKLBFhgAFH6dAAzZGB9EQACUAG1vi4I17wimhSKALrwt5+qPCmN7OTgCrVfGUjSkpplilMnZHBH6pEuEXGgMFgV8mPm4FWjMx232x3O13Ad291M+gY6me6xsGpAALzbo3uJPWt3ba8r6x7ebtBgAbiAGOQp0RyrAEP7RkGsSQIFcYHp-t7JtJDGHI-3vmKhPCHyfF9JyQddljEL98xFbcln0ADSCAwRXwKbZDk-b103baDUM6eETkIXlF1bKCYxgqtN1vUiwLg14LTfA8kGPU9z0IWc2KyPUF31GwgTtABzCAAAkDwYaYxGDJMV2SRRGJPM88QuQRaGAPjY1EAA+cYSG0P54CBJAJIgFw1PvHh4A0G9kj-QQcWsHg3iYQEoB0SAFWUvikC0P59JiJizxiOySAAI0ECAvngkhzIEfMyPWWyJh4WikEcpBnNcoF3M87ykF8uSIAChKeBCsLPgijkLJinDXHixKSAcpyXIgNyVKyhUcr8-LAqQYrwsCY54SAA)

Answer (score 22):

After the Template Literal Types released, you can just use:

```js
type Fields = `${FieldsMap}` // "user-name" | "user-password" | "user-country"
```